# How can I tell what WP7 SDK version a machine is using?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I have a Windows machine, and I'm trying to figure out what version of the Windows Phone 7 SDK is installed on it (and what version a specific project is built with). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `WMAppManifest.xml` you can read out what `AppPlatformVersion` of the SDK you're using.

In `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone` you can see what versions of the SDK are installed.

And in `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` you can see the explicit version of the SDK, such as **"Windows Phone SDK 7.1 (RC) - ENU"** (latest 7.1 developer release)

Answer (score 0):

Look at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\
You should have v7.0 and/or 7.1. If you got only one - that's the SDK. If there are two it's most likely 7.1, yet it is possible that someone set to 7.0.